# How to set row lines separator between flexbox items?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need help - I'm trying to make a simple route visualisation in flex. Flex allow keeping equal distances between elements, which can have different text values. As you can see, I have to make small dots at the bottom of the element and a gray or blue bar when the element is inactive or active, respectively.
Unfortunately, I do not know how to match the blue and gray lines in such a way that they always match the distance between points (its depends on text length in points). I will be grateful for your help.
Below is an attachment that shows what I want to achieve
[image: the effect that I want to achieve]

Comment: please share code waht you have tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really an expert on this, however br might help.

I've found this example on https://tobiasahlin.com/blog/flexbox-break-to-new-row/

```
/* Inserting this collapsed row between two flex items will make 
 * the flex item that comes after it break to a new row */

.break {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  height: 0;
}


<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="break"></div> <!-- break -->
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```